# Get PrivateKey from X509Certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509

Here is my code to generate a SSL certificate using Let's Encrypt (based on https://github.com/zero11it/acme-client):

```
AcmeChallengeListener challengeListener = new HttpChallengeListener(sessionToken, appObjectId, userId, domains[0], "");
Acme acme = new Acme(CA_STAGING_URL, new DefaultCertificateStorage(true), true, true);
X509Certificate cert = acme.getCertificate(domains, AGREEMENT_URL, contacts, challengeListener);
String fullchain = CertificateHelper.x509ToBase64PEMString(cert);
```

Is there a way to get the `PrivateKey` and also get it as String with the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`? So it can be uploaded by our app to our NGINX server.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no way to get a private key out of a X509 Certificate. A Certificate consists of the public parts of the credentials (e.g. the identity of the holder, the issuers, the permissions associated with the certificate, and its public material). There is NOTHING private in a certificate. (You're private key could be associated to your certificate inside a keystore, for sure, but the Certificate itself does not contain a private key).

Comment: How did you generate the key pair?

Comment: The Acme library class does it

Comment: Then the Acme class must also provide a way to access the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to modify the library and expose the certificate storage like this:

`public CertificateStorage getCertificateStorage() {
        return certificateStorage;
    }`

From here the app can get the `PrivateKey`